# Angular2 [2.4.10] Import child component without declaring into AppModule

Tags: angular

I have two components

parent.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-element',
  template: `  <h4>{{title}}</h4>
               <child-element></child-element> //<-- Here I want to take data from child element
              `    
})
export class ParentComponent {
  title = 'This is parent!';
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-element',
  template: `
               <h4>{{childTitle}}</h4>
              `   
})
export class ChildComponent {    
  childTitle = 'This is Child';    
}
```

I tried adding following in parent.component.ts, but it didn't work.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  providers: []
})
```

Another question - If I have number of component and want to communicate with each other. adding all of them in App.module.ts will overhead, isn't it? As they will be loaded up start up. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

parent.component.ts should not have an @NgModule Decorator.

In your app.module, you should have a "declarations" section. All components associated with the module should be included in your declarations array.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent]
})
```

There are several ways for components to communicate with each other.

- Pass data from parent to child with input binding
- Parents listen for child event
- Parent interacts with child via local variable
- Parent calls an @ViewChild()
- Parent and children communicate via a service

This web site has more information on each of those options: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I am concerned about app.module where I have to declare all the components like 50 of them.  Earlier we can use it with 
`directives:[ComponentName]`